# Extracción de datos de una columna dependiendo de otra en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy trabajando con el siguiente [archivo CSV](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv) el cual es un dataset que recoge los casos diarios de COVID-19 organizados por region y país. Con ese conjunto de datos, estoy intentando reportar el país/provincia y la fecha con el mayor número de nuevos casos confirmados a lo largo del periodo de muestreo. Para ello, tengo que calcular los cambios diarios en los casos notificados.

```
# Load the dataset
covid_data <- read.csv("./time_series_covid19_confirmed_global_05022023.csv")

# Omit the NA data
covid_data <- na.omit(covid_data)

# Obtain the total of number of cases per row and region
total_cases <- apply(covid_data[, 5:ncol(covid_data)], 1, sum)

# Combine the cases with the two first columns
country_region <- covid_data[, 1:2]
country_region$total_cases <- total_cases

# Aggregate the total cases per region
total_cases_by_country_province <- aggregate(total_cases ~ Country.Region + Province.State, data = country_region, sum)

# Calculate the daily new confirmed cases for each country/province
daily_cases <- apply(total_cases_by_country_province[, 5:ncol(total_cases_by_country_province)], 1, diff)

daily_cases <- cbind(total_cases_by_country_province[, 1:4], daily_cases)

# Find the maximum number of new confirmed cases
max_cases <- max(daily_cases[, 5:ncol(daily_cases)])

# Find the row and column indices of the maximum number of new confirmed cases
max_cases_indices <- which(daily_cases[, 5:ncol(daily_cases)] == max_cases, arr.ind = TRUE)

# Extract the country/province and date with the maximum number of new confirmed cases
max_cases_country <- daily_cases[max_cases_indices[1], 2]
max_cases_date <- colnames(total_cases_by_country_province)[max_cases_indices[2] + 4]

# Print the results
cat("The country/province with the highest number of new confirmed cases is", max_cases_country, "and the date is", max_cases_date, "with", max_cases, "new cases.\n")
```

El error con el que me encuentro es el siguiente:

```
> daily_cases <- apply(total_cases_by_country_province[, 5:ncol(total_cases_by_country_province)], 1, diff)
Error in apply(total_cases_by_country_province[, 5:ncol(total_cases_by_country_province)],  : 
  object 'total_cases_by_country_province' not found
```

Comment: Revisa el código con el que construyes `total_cases_by_country_province`, por que a la hora de usarlo en el `apply()` no pareciera existir.